# Redmine theme not displaying correctly after upgrade

Tags: redmine

Having an issue and I am not sure where to start, performing an upgrade and the CSS/theme is missing or having issues on my test clone. Everything for the upgrade seems to have gone fine,  I have attached files showing what it looks like. The default theme is working, the classic theme and my theme are not.

The live system Is working fine

```
Redmine 3.3.2.stable.14186
Default administrator account changed
Attachments directory writable
Plugin assets directory writable (./public/plugin_assets)
RMagick available (optional)
ImageMagick convert available (optional)
System info: Linux brisredmine-virtual-machine 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Uptime: 331 days

Environment:
Redmine version 3.3.2.stable.14186
Ruby version 2.0.0-p643 (2015-02-25) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version 4.2.7.1
Environment production
Database adapter Mysql2
SCM:
Subversion 1.8.8
Git 1.9.1
Filesystem
Redmine plugins:
computed_custom_field 1.0.6
redmine_banner 0.1.2-dev
redmine_checklists 3.1.5
redmine_custom_js 0.1.0
redmine_dmsf 1.5.9
redmine_landing_page 0.0.1
redmine_tweaks 1.0.0
```

the test box is not

```
Redmine 3.4.8.stable.17890
Default administrator account changed
Attachments directory writable
Plugin assets directory writable (./public/plugin_assets)
RMagick available (optional)
ImageMagick convert available (optional)
System info: Linux brisredmine-virtual-machine 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Uptime: 4 hours

Environment:
Redmine version 3.4.8.stable.17890
Ruby version 2.4.5-p335 (2018-10-18) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version 4.2.11
Environment production
Database adapter Mysql2
SCM:
Subversion 1.8.8
Git 1.9.1
Filesystem
Redmine plugins:
computed_custom_field 1.0.6
redmine_banner 0.1.2-dev
redmine_checklists 3.1.5
redmine_custom_js 0.1.0
redmine_dmsf 1.5.9
redmine_landing_page 0.0.1
redmine_tweaks 1.0.0
```

Commands I ran are

```
sudo getfacl -R current > permissions.acl
sudo cp -rp current/ current.old
sudo rm -rf current
svn co https://svn.redmine.org/redmine/branches/3.4-stable current
sudo cp -p current.old/config/configuration.yml current/config
sudo cp -p current.old/config/database.yml current/config
sudo cp -rp current.old/files/ current/
sudo cp -rp current.old/public/ current/
sudo cp -rp current.old/plugins/ current/
gem install json
gem cleanup json
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm reload
rvm list known
rvm install 2.4.5
rvm upgrade 2.0.0 2.4.5
gem install passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module

LoadModule passenger_module /home//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/passenger-6.0.1/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/passenger-6.0.1
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>

sudo setfacl --restore=permissions.acl
gem update --system
bundle install --without development test
bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
sudo service apache2 restart
```

[image: What the Site looks like]

[image: The default theme is working fine]

[image: The classic theme has the same issue as my theme]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I have been copying over the public folder (../public/stylesheets/application.css) from the old system on top of the new version efectivly clobbering the default.

In future only copy over the custom theme